# Generalisation of Rademacher functions?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

**Background**

Let $\omega$ be in $[0,1]$ and let $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots a_k\dots$ be the binary expansion of $\omega$

It is known that the Rademacher functions $R_k$ defined on the unit interval $I:=[0,1]$ such that

$$ R_k(\omega) = +1 \text{ if } a_k=1$$ and $$R_k(\omega) = -1 \text{ if } a_k = 0$$ always partitions $I$ into $2^k$ intervals.

**Question**

Let $\omega$ in $[0,1]$ and let $0.a_1a_2a_3 \dots a_k \dots $ be the base $g$ expansion of $\omega$ (this expansion always exists and can be found to be unique), is it true that the following function

$$S_k(\omega) = 1+m \text{ if } a_k = m $$

always partitions $I$ into a finite number of intervals, for $m\in \{0,1,2,3 \dots ,g-1\}$?